# OpenLDAP and Existing Local Users

Tags: openldap

I am configuring OpenLDAP on my Linux server, with the intention of using it with the SOGo groupware package, among other things.

In general, I assume it is inadvisable to have an LDAP user with the same name as a local user, or does it matter? If I login to the server as local user `tohuw`, is there an issue with having an LDAP user of the same name, assuming the uid is different?

Or, should I be importing that user somehow? In short, I am unclear on the best practices for introducing LDAP to an established Linux server. My user would have an email address in the SOGo system, and my understanding is that this would require an inetorgperson entry.

Thank you.

Comment: `In general, I assume it is inadvisable to have an LDAP user with the same name as a local user` <-- Explain your assumption. For what reason is this true? If you can't give solid reasons chances are your assumption is invalid and should be rejected in favor of a more nuanced analysis...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voretaq7 was quite correct. It was not clear to me that the objectClass `posixAccount` does not imply an actual entry in /etc/passwd. It is fine to have overlapping names in general, as LDAP and "files" are separate authentication sources. Obviously, it is possible to create conflicts, but in general, the mere existence of a duplicate name in LDAP and files is not a problem.